# Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress - for multiple instance

Tags: wordpress

- My system is running 2 MySQL instance
- One is running on port 3306 another on port 3307
- Now I want to connect my WordPress to MySQL which is running on port 3307

But I am getting error when I try to access index page - Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

Please let me guide how to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the definition of `DB_HOST` in your `wp-config.php` file by adding `:3307`. From [**the documentation**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#MySQL_Alternate_Port):

> If your host uses an alternate port number for your database you'll
>   need to change the DB_HOST value in the wp-config.php file to reflect
>   the alternate port provided by your host.
>
> For localhost
>
> `define( 'DB_HOST', 'localhost:3307' );`
>
> Other
>
> `define( 'DB_HOST', 'mysql.example.com:3307' );`
>
> Replace 3307 with whatever port number your host gives you.

Comment: Did it but problem not resolved. Do I need to change configuration in PHP?

Comment: Is that a brand new installed server? install the mysql client!

Comment: @AdrianPreuss asked the right question: have you verified that you can connect to the database in PHP, independently of WordPress?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was silly mistake from me. Problem in php.ini - wrong directory path, as it is copied from another system. Resolved long back, sorry for late reply.

Answer (score -1):

**Solution 1:**

Check your php.ini and make sure that you have `extension=php_mysql.dll` un-commented.

**Solution 2:**

You can use the following library if you do not have mysql_connect enabled but have PDO enabled:

https://github.com/AzizSaleh/mysql

Create a new file: wp-content/db.php and place this code in it (update your path to mysql with path to your extracted folder):

```
<?php
$pathToMySQL = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\mysql\\';
require_once($pathToMySQL . 'MySQL_Definitions.php');
require_once($pathToMySQL . 'MySQL.php');
require_once($pathToMySQL . 'MySQL_Functions.php');
```

Comment: dont touch the **Core**!

Comment: @AdrianPreuss Good point. I will update it so that it doesn't use the core.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was silly mistake from me. Problem in php.ini - wrong directory path, as it is copied from another system. Resolved long back, sorry for late reply.

Comment: @AdrianPreuss I have updated it so that it doesn't use core files anymore. It uses the stand alone db.php file that is empty by default.